# Office.Js best method for notifying and syncing end user of updates from another system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

Office.JS is presenting some challenges that seem to end in the same you can't do that loop.

We have a system that's used to create appointments and tasks based on certain variables.  What we're struggling with is the best method to sync those events/appointments to the end user.

We've landed with sending the user letting them know there is pending items, but is there a way to embed office.js into the email to open the task pane to sync the two systems?

I know event-based exists, but forcing a sync when composing any email seems crazy.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why close, you don't like questions about a product?

Comment: Can you make your scenario a little more clear? Is some service running on some other platform that are creating appointments that you want to show for the end user?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to open a task pane programmatically from Outlook web add-ins.

A task pane can be displayed by using the following mechanisms that require end user actions as well:

1. A ribbon button can be assigned to open a task pane.
2. A notification message can be configured programmatically at runtime to open a task pane.

If you need to synchronize items in Outlook I'd suggest handling `onSend` event (or [smart alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough)) where you can read all the data of an item being sent and sync it with your back end server. Also you may consider using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) for syncing all items, not only the current one.

Outlook web-based add-ins are designed to work for a particular (currently selected) item only. And they are still very limited, comparing to VSTO add-ins, in customizing the Outlook UI.